# MySQL / Laravel structure: monolith tables, or thousands of small tables?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-10

**Short Version:**

Our webapp works with sets of scoped `project` data - that is, model relationships that will always relate to models in the same `project`, and strictly never cross over into other `project`s. Security / opacity between projects is a key requirement. The whole scoped relational ecosystem spans ~20 database tables so far.

We are currently managing this ecosystem with ~20 monolith tables, and enforcing opacity / security through code - but we're losing our grasp on it. We're considering adopting a structure where each `project` deploys its own clone of these ~20 tables into the same database. Are there any known fundamental drawbacks to having thousands of tables in one database, like increased storage size, slower performance, higher indexing overhead? Our team just doesn't have the database expertise to speak to flaws that might be introduced by this ourselves.

If it makes any difference, we're using Laravel 10 - all models and relationships take advantage of Laravel / Eloquent structures. We're anticipating at least 200 projects active at a time, with a few being added or nuked each month.

---

**Long Version:** We have an internal-use project org / management webapp, with some complicated requirements.

In broad strokes, there are `projects`, and each `project` has several related entities - `permissions`, `reports`, `tickets`, `labels`, `ticket_label`, `media`, `notifications`, many more. All related entities are scoped to their project - reports, labels, tickets, etc created inside a project by definition will never be transitioned to another, and no entities are generalized to multiple projects. Our project shareholders are adamant that a project's information is totally secure and opaque from other projects - no project should know any other project exists, and when a project is deleted there shouldn't be a trace of it left.

It's a little messy, because all these entities are binned into single tables with each other, regardless of project. There's extra work and middleware going into, for example, making sure some bad actor can't reassign a ticket ID in from an external project to gain access to its data. It's also complicated deleting a project and ensuring all nested / related data has been wiped - we get pretty far with appropriate foreign_keys and `->onDelete( 'cascade' )`, but as the app gets more developed it's more and more difficult to **guarantee** that all data has been scrubbed when a project is deleted. There have been a few incidents where orphans containing sensitive information have been discovered. We've been improving our tests and code when each is discovered, but it's becoming clear that we can't guarantee fallthroughs won't happen again - shareholders are expressing doubts.

Someone brought up that we can reduce a lot of complexity if we're able to generate a group of tables each time a new project is created. So, when project `0f9ebA2` is created, it creates tables `0f9ebA2_reports`, `0f9ebA2_tickets`, and so on as well. These tables will be identical structurally, so can all be created from the same migrations. In terms of convenience and cleanliness, the advantages are clear - foreign keys will be pointed to tables with the same prefix, and guarantee IDs outside of the project can't be assigned. It's also trivial to ensure all data has been scrubbed - just delete the tables. Many of the cross-pollination protections become obsolete, reduced to just access permissions.

The main rub is that noone on our team has deep enough database experience to speak to potential performance or integrity flaws with this approach - and it doesn't seem like a common practice in MySQL, so there aren't a lot of articles or forums on the subject. We'd like to get another perspective on this, and see if we're overlooking any fundamental flaws before we pull the trigger - like increased storage size, slower performance, higher indexing overhead. Matters of MySQL architecture and performance, over best practice and opinion.

Comment: "Are there any major database drawbacks to this approach, like drastically lower performance?" -- I would say no. However, there will be an admin cost to have 200 separate apps each one talking to its own database. They would need to be deployed separately and managed separately for security purposes.

Comment: only you know your requirements, but I find it hard believe there will never be any need for cross-project reports etc.  but even if so, I'd definitely stick to one set tables, but ensure that every table has a project_id, even if it is nested data (project has tickets has ticket history)

Comment: I had this issue in a company a few months ago, the solution is to have a single database/schema and have everything there. You may need to have a project per customer, which is a nightmare when deploying code, imagine running migrations for each schema and making sure none gets out of sync? Just correctly use Policies, Gates, and Tests to assert you are never exposing stuff that should not be exposed to someone

Comment: If your business stakeholders are serious about having no trace of a project when deleted, then I don't think you have much other option, but to store each project in its own set of tables, preferably in their own database as you will not be able to remove the project data from **backups** . If backups contain the deleted project data, then backup -> delete project X -> application issue -> database restore sequence of events will restore project X fully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few years ago I managed the databases at a company that had about 10,000 schemas, each schema had the same set of ~120 tables. They did this for similar reasons that you have, to make sure data for different clients is kept separate, for privacy and security reasons.

This was on MySQL 5.1 at the time. We found that after a few tens of thousands of tables on a given server, performance became a problem. It turns out that MySQL has internal data structures corresponding to each table, and they didn't architect this to handle so many tables. So eventually scanning lists of open tables becomes a bottleneck.

We split the schemas over seven servers, so each server didn't have so many tables. About 160,000 tables per server was our maximum.

I gave feedback to the MySQL product manager about this bottleneck, as they were developing a revamped implementation of the data dictionary for MySQL 8.0. He passed this along to the engineers, and they made sure to test scalability up to 1 million tables per server.

So definitely make sure that you use MySQL 8.0 or later to get this improvement.

But even with MySQL 8.0, this doesn't give you unlimited scalability. Eventually if you intend to keep growing, you must develop the capability to store data on more than one database server, and your applications need to have code to switch between database servers.

For example, in our case, one of the db servers had a simple table that stored a list of all the clients and which db server their data was stored on. This list was read at the startup of the app, and held in cache. It was a simple mapping list. Then on any request, the app could quickly tell which of seven db servers it should send the query. All the functions to run queries had an argument which was the db connection to use.

So in a way, "are there any performance limitations" is the wrong question. The assumption should be that there *are* performance limitations, it's just a matter of how large can you grow until you hit those limits. Assume that you will.

Then the question is how to keep growing beyond those limits, and that means scaling out to multiple servers. Build this into your application design.

---

> The main rub is that noone on our team has deep enough database experience to speak to potential performance or integrity flaws with this approach

Well, now's your opportunity to exercise your general software engineering skills, and develop some tests.

You — or *someone* on your team — hopefully have a degree in Computer Science? Well, approach the problem like a scientist. What type of tests would measure scalability of this kind? Presumably you'd need a lab where you could build a database with lots of tables. You'd need some scripts that can populate those tables, probably with a parameter so you can re-run the test at different scale. You'd need some way to drive query traffic in a repeatable fashion, and measure performance.

Then you need to develop requirements for scalability. What performance is acceptable? What rate of degradation is acceptable? Who gets to decide this?

No one starts with these skills. *They learn as they work.* "I don't have those skills" is not an excuse. They try something, they make mistakes, learn from them, improve their processes.

You also need to learn that optimization and scalability is not about choosing the right technology. No technology scales if you use it improperly. Scalability comes from architecture, which should be where you have software engineering skills.

Comment: Outstanding answer - thanks! I fully agree "I don't have those skills" isn't an excuse, just an admission that my team needs to learn more so we *can* execute (which you've helped greatly in).

Comment: One more point: the limit my company reached was at 160k tables. That was for _our_ application workload, on _our_ servers, on MySQL 5.1. All of those factors are obviously different for you, and they will change further over time. This is why you have to test your own application on your servers to see where you reach the limit. Then test again from time to time in the future.